# Como ajustar un elemento al medio de la pantalla?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Llevo mas de una hora pensando en como poder ajustar los cuadrados al lado central derecho.
Están en la parte superior derecha y quiero que se ajusten al centro derecho que queden como la imagen de abajo.

*Así me queda:*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Así necesito que me quede:*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Así es como he intentado:*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi `index.html`,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./asset/css/style.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color:#1195EA;">
    <main class = "container">
        <section class="flex flex-wrap" style="justify-content: flex-end;align-items: flex-end;flex-direction: column;">
            <article></article>
            <article></article>
            <article></article>
            <article></article>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
```

y este es mi `css`.

```
/* elimina cualquier margen o padding que tenga por defecto un navegador*/
*{
padding: 0px;
margin:0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

.flex{
display: flex;
}

.flex-wrap{
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

article{
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
margin: 10px;
background-color: #11EAD6;
 }
```

Comment: Agrega tu código como texto por favor, de otra manera es complicado ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compañero, una forma sería **envolviendo** con un div el elemento que quieres centrar verticalmente y hacer uso del **posicionamiento** y de **transform** como te muestro a continuación en el código.

**Index**:

```
<body style="background-color:#1195EA;">
<main class = "container">
    <div class="centrar-verticalmente">
        <section class="flex flex-wrap" style="justify-content: flex-end;align-items: flex-end;flex-direction: column;">
            <article></article>
            <article></article>
            <article></article>
            <article></article>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>
```

**CSS** (añadir):

```
.centrar-verticalmente{
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 94%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**Resultado:**
[image: prueba]

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, pero podría ser una opción para salir del paso :)

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias maneras de [centrar verticalmente](https://www.dariobf.com/centrar-verticalmente-con-css-6-formas-diferentes-de-lograrlo/), la que yo más suelo usar es con [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ya que creo que es la más fácil, pero también depende de de lo que necesites. Ya que lo que estas haciendo es maquetando toda la página, creo que sería mejor si usas [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) para estructurar todos los elementos

```css
.container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
}

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 5;
}

.content-left {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 4;
}

.content-rigth {
  grid-area: 2 / 4 / 3 / 5;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 5;
}

/* elimina cualquier margen o padding que tenga por defecto un navegador*/
*{
padding: 0px;
margin:0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #11EAD6;
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <div class="header"> </div>
  <div class="content-left"> </div>
  <section class="content-rigth">
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
  </section>
  <div class="footer"> </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo antes de mirar nada de flex me hice el tutorial de esta web. https://flexboxfroggy.com/#es